# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character when parsing output from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

My php returns something as such:

```
  if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    echo $db->error;
      die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
  }
  echo 'Total results: ' . $result->num_rows . "\n";

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      echo json_encode($row);
      echo "\n";
  }
```

In my javascript, I want to put the output on the page if it's a json object or just log it to the console if it's something else:

```
var divOutput = function(output) {
  try {
    // var x = output.trim();
    // x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
    var x = JSON.parse(output);
    console.log(x);
    $("#dbOut").html(JSON.stringify(x, null, '\t'));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(output);
    console.log(e);
  }
}

var getPlayerByID = function() {
  var myNumber = document.getElementById("PlayerInput").value;
  $.ajax({
    url : "db_funcs.php",
    data : {
      action : 'getPlayerByID',
      a : myNumber,
    },
    type : 'post',
    success : function(output) {
      divOutput(output);
    }
```

However it's throwing the JSON parse error when I query the database. How can I do this?
})
}

Comment: Have you tested your JSON at jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws the error because you are not **only** echoing json.

In the line

```
echo 'Total results: ' . $result->num_rows . "\n"
```

You already echo something which is not json encoded. 
With this code it should work:

```
//echo 'Total results: ' . $result->num_rows . "\n";  <---- this is not json
$arr = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $arr[] = $row; //save each row in array
    //echo "\n";
}
echo json_encode($arr); //encode all data as json
```

If you want the number of rows also in the json output add it in the `$arr` with a key like

```
$arr["num_rows"] = $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: ah, ok. I thought the try/catch statement would handle that.

Comment: Nope, it sees the whole output as one thing and therefor it crashes. You can mark one of the answers given such that other users know how the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

JSON must be output as a SINGLE monolithic json string. You're building multiple SEPARATE json strings, which is illegal syntax.

Consider JSON to be pretty much equivalent to the right-hand side of a javascript variable assignment:

```
var foo = this_part_is_json;
```

e.g. you need to have

```
var foo = [[stuff from row 1], [stuff from row2], etc...];
```

but are producing

```
var foo = [stuff from row1][stuff from row2];
                           ^---syntax error would occur here
```

You need

```
$arr = array();
while($row = fetch from db) {
   $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  echo json_encode($row);
  echo "\n";
}
```

Try like this

```
$arr = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $arr[] = ($row);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Use `json_encode()` only once, use arrays to store values in `while()`